# How do I create a cron expression running in Kibana on weekday?

Tags: elasticsearch, cron, kibana, elastic-stack

I would like my watcher to run from Monday to Friday only. So I'm trying to use this schedule:

```
"trigger": {
    "schedule" : { "cron" : "0 0 0/4 * * MON-FRI" }
  },
  "input": {
  ...
```

However, I'm getting

```
Error
Watcher: [parse_exception] could not parse [cron] schedule
```

when I'm trying to save the watcher. Removing `MON-FRI` does helps but I need it.

This expression works:

```
0 0 0/4 ? * MON-FRI
```

But I'm not sure I understand why [`?` is required for either the `day_of_week` or `day_of_month`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/6.3/trigger-schedule.html)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
"0 0 0/4 ? * MON-FRI"
```

You can use croneval to check your cron expressions [1](https://cinhtau.net/2017/07/08/evaluating-watcher-cron-expression/):

```
$ /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/x-pack/croneval "0 0 0/4 ? * MON-FRI"
Valid!
Now is [Mon, 20 Aug 2018 13:32:26]
Here are the next 10 times this cron expression will trigger:
1.      Mon, 20 Aug 2018 09:00:00
2.      Mon, 20 Aug 2018 13:00:00
3.      Mon, 20 Aug 2018 17:00:00
4.      Mon, 20 Aug 2018 21:00:00
5.      Tue, 21 Aug 2018 01:00:00
6.      Tue, 21 Aug 2018 05:00:00
7.      Tue, 21 Aug 2018 09:00:00
8.      Tue, 21 Aug 2018 13:00:00
9.      Tue, 21 Aug 2018 17:00:00
10.     Tue, 21 Aug 2018 21:00:00
```

For the first expression you'll get following java exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.

You can also use [Crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*_0/4_*_*_MON-FRI) to get human readable descriptions like:

> At every minute past every 4th hour from 0 through 23 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark means 'No Specific value'. From the documentation on Quartz's website:

? (“no specific value”) - useful when you need to specify something in one of the two fields in which the character is allowed, but not the other. For example, if I want my trigger to fire on a particular day of the month (say, the 10th), but don’t care what day of the week that happens to be, I would put “10” in the day-of-month field, and “?” in the day-of-week field. See the examples below for clarification.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

I suppose since you want your schedule to run every 4 hours, mon-fri, the actual day of the month is irrelevant, so the ? specifies that. * on teh other hand would be 'all values' which would not make sense since you are specifying only mon-fri for day of the week. 
Hope that helps!